# Choosing most liked post from facebook group

Tags: javascript, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-apps-script

Well, here is the json file http://herbalista.hol.es/group.json i am working with JSON.parse(); on Google apps script. I temporarily solve with this code by Choosing the post which have more than 15 likes, but i want to choose the one with more likes independently if have or not more than 15 likes.

```
function repost() {
var UsrAccess_token = "xxxxxxxxx"
var graph = "https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxx/feed/?access_token="+UsrAccess_token+"";
var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(graph,{method:"get"}).getContentText();
var object = JSON.parse(jsondata);
var item = object.data;
var currentTime = new Date();
var year = currentTime.getUTCFullYear();
var month = (currentTime.getUTCMonth()) + 1;
var day = (currentTime.getUTCDate()) - 1;
if (day <= 9) {var day = "0"+day+"";}
if (month <= 9) {var month = "0"+month+"";}
var utime = ""+year+"-"+month+"-"+day+"T";
try {
var i = null;
for (i = 0; item.length > i; i += 1) {
var pubDate = item[i].created_time;
if (pubDate.match(utime)) { var likesdata = item[i].likes.data; var len = likesdata.length;
                           if (len > 15) {var popular = item[i].link;}}


}} catch(err) {
   var err = "ERROR";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can Choose a default value for a variable like `var maxLikes = 0;` and verify against `len` variable.

The code would be something like this:

```
function repost() {
var UsrAccess_token = "xxxxxxxxx"
var graph = "https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxx/feed/?access_token="+UsrAccess_token+"";
var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(graph,{method:"get"}).getContentText();
var object = JSON.parse(jsondata);
var item = object.data;
var currentTime = new Date();
var year = currentTime.getUTCFullYear();
var month = (currentTime.getUTCMonth()) + 1;
var day = (currentTime.getUTCDate()) - 1;
if (day <= 9) {var day = "0"+day+"";}
if (month <= 9) {var month = "0"+month+"";}
var utime = ""+year+"-"+month+"-"+day+"T";
try {
  var i = null;
  var maxLikes = 0; 
  for (i = 0; item.length > i; i += 1) {
    var pubDate = item[i].created_time;
    if (pubDate.match(utime)) { 
      var likesdata = item[i].likes.data;
      var len = likesdata.length;
      if (len > maxLikes) {
        maxLikes = len;
        var popular = item[i].link;
      }
    }
  }
} catch(err) {
   var err = "ERROR";
}
```

}

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks in advance for your answer, i try it but it says thet the most liked post have 6.0 likes but really the most liked post have 39.0 likes and i don't know why...

Comment: My original code runs well but I do not want to rely on a default value because the code will always choose the higher than the default but if there is no higher it will choose no one and the idea is that the code will always choose one: the highest independently if is or not highest than the default.

Comment: I can't make any sense of your comment Herbalist, KRR code is working fine, `maxLikes` is the highest likes in the current date and `popular` is that post, if you need more help redo your question with added details or start another question.

Comment: @  Herbalist Etnobiología, If you have not added your requirement clearly, please edit your question.

Comment: Thanks by your help, I got confused and I apologize...I will be monitoring the code and if I encounter any problems I will be commenting...